# vscode: share gitlab link to line under cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

My pattern when I share code

- navigate to some code in VSCode, view blamed COMMIT in GitLens
- add commit to `gitlab/.../commits` and manually construct link

Is there any VSCode extension for creating links:

- open blamed commit under current line in GitLab?
- open file under cursor in GitLab tree ?

Comment: Why do I even need an extension for this thing? Half of my job is constantly sharing permanent commit tied code line links, which should work a year after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) installed, put the cursor on the relevant line, hit `Ctrl+Shift+P` to trigger the command palette, and search for "Gitlens: Open File on Remote".

Comment: Or if you just want to copy the current selected lines link: “Gitlens: Copy Remote File URL"

Answer (score 2):

**Git History** is the extension for accessing the git blame features in VS code. You can view blamed commit associated to a specific line by installing this extension.

[image]

**Git Graph** is the extension for getting look at your gitlab project graph.

This is the link for detailed overview of git graph extension:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9ZQpKGTog4

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [git lense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension has small earth icon in line tooltip "open in gitlab", which opens just last blamed commit